# WPF client does not catch custom exception from WCF

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I have a custom exception and this works fine when the client is console application or forms application, but if the client is `WPF` not works. look but still I found no answer, any idea?

My basic custom error code:

```
[DataContract]   
public class BookingException
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Messsage { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

service interface code:

```
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(BookingException))]  
void InsertBooking(Booking booking);
```

service code:

```
public void InsertBooking(Booking booking)
{
    throw new FaultException<BookingException>(new BookingException());  
}
```

Client code:

```
 catch (FaultException<BookingException> ex)
 {
       //TODO
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
       //TODO
 }
```

This works fine when the client is a console application or forms application, but if this client code I put in WPF application, always the catch is the Exception, not the custom exceptions.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the `Exception ex` block and see _exactly_ what the exception type is. It is almost certainly your custom exception, but in a different namespace. This will have _nothing_ to do with the fact that you've got a WPF project. It will have to do with the fact that you have a _different_ project, and your project settings are different or you did the "Add Service Reference" differently. For instance, is the WPF project a new one? Then maybe you didn't add a reference to a shared assembly which is added in the other projects.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thaks for you comment. I create a new WPF project and the error is the same, but if I create a console application works fine. The namespace of the project is the same in both, buts only works in the console applications. I not found the diference...

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd is the same thread

Comment: Check the versions of .NET used in the two projects. Check the list of assembly and project references between the two projects. If worse come to worst, add to the WPF project any assemblies that the Console project has but the WPF project does not (even if you don't believe the WPF project needs those assemblies). Maybe also create a new Console application and give it all the same assemblies the WPF project has. Make _certain_ you use the _exact_ same "Add Service Reference" command in both projects.

Comment: @JohnSaunders before asking here, I did these test. anyway I will return them to do. Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: @JohnSaunders by the way, I use the same proxy, but when I use WPF thrugh the project is not working

Comment: You use the same proxy? Is it defined in the WPF project, or in a different project?

Comment: @JohnSaunders different project. Both project (console application and WPF application) have these in reference

Comment: Try to make one tiny library (third project) that contains only this one exception, and then reference that library and use that exception in both projects.

Comment: In this case, "I don't believe you". There is something else happening. .NET has no idea that one project is WPF and the other is not. If the custom exception is being caught in one place, then it should be caught in the other. Try fully-qualifying the name of the custom exception in both projects and test them both again.

Comment: I "don't believe" too... but this not works and I not found the problem....

Comment: Works!!! @JohnSaunders you have reason, are diferent proxy (in many tests I change it) The proxys not implement of the same way the service... I thought I had reviewed it, but the problem was this. Thanks you, very much for your time.

Comment: Please add this information as an answer. You can even accept it. It would be best if you said what steps you took that finally made you realize you had two different proxies. That way, your answer will benefit others in the same situation (and you'll get more upvotes that way).

Comment: @JohnSaunders Ok, I will do, thank you again for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with the comments helps. I have two proxys, one in my console application and other in my WPF applications, boths proxys use the same service reference, but both proxys have the diferente way the reference the service, this diference was the problem. 
`WPF not have any problems with custom erros`.
Thanks to those who helped me with their comments.